# Getting 4200 pdo error after porting from xampp to server.

Tags: pdo

My problem is that I'm getting a 4200 error code from my pdo insert. On my computer when I was working with XAMPP it worked fine (no error) but as soon as I ported it onto the server I got this error. Could someone enlighten me or point me in the direction to get the answer. Thanks.

```
 $add_nonce = $db->con->prepare("INSERT INTO nonces(nonce, issue_date, `used`) VALUES(:nonce, :issue_date, '0')");
        $add_nonce->bindParam(':nonce', $nonce, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $issue_date = time();
        $add_nonce->bindParam(':issue_date', $issue_date, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $add_nonce->execute();
    Log_String("test", $add_nonce->errorCode());
    $nonce_id = $db->con->lastInsertId();
    return $nonce;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of logging just error code, you have to tell PDO to throw *exception*, which contains also full error message.

```
$db->con->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
```

Instead of home-brewed Log_String() function you have to tell PHP to log all errors by default, using `log_errors` and `error_log` ini directives.

Or, if on development server, just turn `display_errors` on.

And you will immediately know what's going wrong.

Comment: Thank you. I should be able to figure out the error with this.